# Determine If Sandbox from Instance URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sandbox, oauth, instance

There's been a few questions around working out if an org is a sandbox or not, but typically these are done via Apex. I need to find out an org's type (only sandbox/prod - dev etc. don't matter) using just the instance URL in Javascript from a Node application.

**Current Solution**

Worst case scenario I use a REST API call to query the org type and determine the state of play, but the best I've come up with from Javascript right now is to use regex:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(".*cs[0-9]{1,2}(\.my)?\.salesforce.com");
return pattern.test(instance);
```

This will return `true` for URLs such as "https://cs22.salesforce.com", "https://lacey.cs22.my.salesforce.com" and `false` for things like "https://na1.salesforce.com".

**Question**

Am I missing anything obvious here? Is there some format of Sandbox url I'm not catering for?

It *doesn't* need to work for every conceivable string thrown at it, it's working on the `instanceUrl` returned by Salesforce along with the access tokens etc. during the OAuth flow. What I need is something that's *good enough* for 99% of the orgs out there right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you need it all, but the following additional subdomains come to my mind, which might not be covered by your current regex:

- visualforce domain urls
- namespaced managed packages
- lightning urls
- salesforce one app

Comment: Yeah, I thought of these but I don't think they ever play a part in login thankfully!

Answer (score 3):

[Based on the Salesforce PM response here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=0873000000083sJAAQ), you can safely determine based on the instance url. Issue will be if you are using a custom my domain, then you will have to write a Rest API to expose the status.

Comment: Yeah I think for login the my custom ones aren't too much of an issue...